# How to run bash script on MacOS GitHub's workflow?

Tags: macos, github, github-actions

During CMake step I configure `path.sh` file with the following content:

```
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_OPENSSL@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_FREETYPE@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_LIBJPEG@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_LIBPNG@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_BZIP2@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_BROTLI@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=@CONAN_LIB_DIRS_ZLIB@:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /Users/runner/.bash_profile
```

I just want to set up `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` with Conan's libraries.

In GitHub workflow file I have:

```
- name: Append DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with packages' lib directories
  run: ${{ github.workspace }}/path.sh
```

But it fails with:

```
/Users/runner/work/_temp/....sh: line 1: /Users/runner/work/.../path.sh: Permission denied
```

How can I run bash script on MacOS GitHub's workflow?

I solved the problem with another approach, but the subject... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `chmod +x` to your run:

```
env:
  DYLD_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/path.sh
jobs:.....
    - name: Append DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with packages' lib directories
      run: |
        chmod +x ${{ DYLD_PATH }}
        ${{ DYLD_PATH }}
```

Comment: Hm, permission was denied because of missing executable mod... Thank you.